# Does need devm_iounmap when rmmod, which module use devm* api?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

The `devm_ioremap()` API use device resource management framework, no need to unmap when driver probe fail.

What about the module when the module is unloaded? Need to be released too?

Answer (score 3):

## No, it's not needed.

The design goal of the managed resource API (the `devm_` stuff) is to avoid calling `unmap`, `free`, etc. when a device is released, either because of failure or removal.

The `devm_iounmap` and similar is only there when you need to roll-back a previous call to `devm_ioremap`.

Official doc here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/devres.txt

I suggest that you take a look at how drivers do it in the kernel. Learning by reading the code is a great path in the Linux Kernel.